# My Objects overwritten in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object, typescript

I have a function that receives object each time it is called, I want to store this object in an Array. But when I push the arrived Object in the Array the previous Object is overwritten. How do I save the Objects without overwriting the previous ones each time am in the function, so that all the objects are printed in the for() function.

```
 drawtimeline(i_items, nom_cal, _hitoService, idcalbuscador) {
    var container = document.getElementById('timeLine');
     var result: any[] = [];
      result.push({  "_id": this.idcalbuscador, "title": nom_cal });
     for (let i of result) {
   console.log(i); 
         alert(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `result` variable is local to the `drawtimeline` function. When that function finishes executing, the `result` variable is cleared. When that function is called again, a new `result` array is allocated, which makes it look like you are clearing the old object stored in the array. Each time you run the function you're printing a separate array containing the single object you just pushed.

The solution is to pull the `result` variable out of the function and into the outer scope. The details will depend on if this function is part of a module, a class, or bare. Typically it will look like this:

```
var result: any[] = [];
drawtimeline(i_items, nom_cal, _hitoService, idcalbuscador) {
    var container = document.getElementById('timeLine');

    result.push({  "_id": this.idcalbuscador, "title": nom_cal });
    for (let i of result) {
        console.log(i); 
        alert(i);
    }
}
```

If you are in a class, you will need to use `this.result`